# Suggest full text search engine for continuous concurrent read writes and updates

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, full-text-search, solr

Our application needs multiple concurrent read write simultaneously and NRT searches. We have been using Solr till now and with minor tweaks in the solr configuration we have managed to sort our occasional issues like Indexes locking up ect.

We are gearing up for massive scale and I'm not sure if Solr will hold up. I mean there were a lot many parallel read/writes happening on solr index. One of the articles that I read recently says that solr breaks on concurrent searching and index updates.

http://engineering.socialcast.com/2011/05/realtime-search-solr-vs-elasticsearch/

Please suggest if solr will fit our requirement or we need to switch to something else.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn uses Lucene, and they seem to do just fine. They have a a project ([Zoie](http://javasoze.github.com/zoie/)) to help them with realtime updates which you might want to look into.